pytest fixture representing a cache directory or cross-session temp dir
What I'm looking for
I'm looking for a Python package that provides a pytest fixture representing a "cache directory" that persists between pytest invocations (but may be deleted between reboots or to free up disk space, as with any cache).
It would be a (semi-)persistent analogue of the builtin fixtures for temporary directories.
Alternatives
I saw that pytest does support keeping values in cache across sessions, so an alternative would be to just zip up a temp dir, put it in that value cache, and have a fixture unpack it in the next session. But that can become quite resource-intensive if the directory is large, defeating the purpose of a cache.
